# Как работает `elem.string` в `[elem.string for elem in page.find_all(class_="list_aut")]`?

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, beautiful-soup

Задача стоит такая: нужно после парсинга страницы из элементов массива достать нужный текст. Массив получен при помощи библиотеки Beautiful Soup: `yourArr = page.find_all(class_="list_aut")`
Т.е. элемент массива такой:

```html
<div class="list_aut"><a href="http://slova.textologia.ru/definit/abazhur/?q=657&amp;n=1000">Абажур</a></div>
```

И из него надо достать "Абажур". В интернете нашёл такое решение:`solution = [elem.string for elem in yourArr]` Оно рабочее, на выходе получаю массив с нужными данными. Но можете объяснить как работает данная строчка? В частности что за `elem.string`. В документации ничего не смог найти.

Comment: было бы неплохо указать в вопросе как вы получили `yourArr`

Comment: Добавил способ получения

Comment: Для каждого `elem` из `yourArr` вернуть `elem.string`, где в `elem` "кладётся" элемент массива из текущей итерации цикла.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если функция `page.find_all()` что-то нашла, то она вернет список элементов типа `bs4.element.Tag`. У `bs4.element.Tag` существует атрибут `.string`.